# Routing for nested modules in Angular 2 RC5/Router 3 RC1

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router3

Let's say I have the following setup:

```
employee -------+ employee.module.ts
                | employee.routing.ts
                + employee.component.ts
                |
sales ----------+ sales.module.ts
                | sales.routing.ts
                + sales.component.ts
app.module.ts
app.routing.ts
app.component.ts
```

and I'd like my routes to look like

```
employee/14/sales
```

So I go ahead and define these routing declarations:

**app.routing.ts**

```
...
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: AppComponent }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true });
```

**employee.routing.ts**

```
...
import { EmployeeComponent } from './employee.component';

export const employeeRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'employee/:id', component: EmployeeComponent }  
];

export const employeeRouting = RouterModule.forChild(employeeRoutes);
```

**sales.routing.ts**

```
...
import { SalesComponent } from './sales.component';

export const salesRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'sales', component: SalesComponent }  
];

export const salesRouting = RouterModule.forChild(salesRoutes);
```

while my modules take this form:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { EmployeeModule } from './employee/employee.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import {
    routing,
    appRoutingProviders
} from './app.routing';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        EmployeeModule,
        routing
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        appRoutingProviders
    ]
})
```

**employee.module.ts**

```
import { SalesModule } from '../sales/sales.module';
import { EmployeeComponent } from './employee.component';
import { employeeRouting } from './employee.routing';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        SalesModule,
        employeeRouting
    ],
    declarations: [
        EmployeeComponent
    ]
})
```

**sales.module.ts**

```
import { SalesComponent } from './sales.component';
import { salesRouting } from './sales.routing';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        salesRouting
    ],
    declarations: [
        SalesComponent
    ]
})
export class SalesModule {}
```

I can now move to

```
employee/14
```

but if I try to navigate to

```
employee/14/sales
```

I'm greeted with

> Error: Cannot match any routes: 'employee/14/sales'

I can, however, enter

```
sales
```

and that works while it isn't supposed to work, so somehow all routes connect directly to `/` instead of building on top of each other.

What am I missing?

**EDIT** plnkr demonstrating the issue can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/CatPo9fpsJwM7ErQa5n6?p=preview).

Comment: How do you navigate to `employee/14/sales` and from where? routerLink? If yes what component contains it? Have you tried `/employee/14/sales` instead?

Comment: No, I have that issue in a largish project so I built a quick sample application to be able to reproduce it; within that sample app I simply type in the browser address bar like `http://localhost:3000/#/employee/14/sales`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I eventually got this to work. The key idea is not to include `employeeRoutes` from `employee.routing.ts` (as that will add stuff from `EmployeeModule` to `AppModule`s declarations and result in yet another error message) but instead to create another `employeeRoutes` inside `app.routing.ts` that will lazy load `EmployeeModule` when navigating to a route starting with`

```
/employee
```

Here's the relevant code:

```
import {
    RouterModule,
    Routes
} from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

const employeeRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'employee',
    loadChildren: 'app/employee/employee.module#EmployeeModule'
  }
];

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' },
    ...employeeRoutes
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true });
```

The full plnkr can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/aey1jTdc72vN5voqkVFZ?p=preview).

Comment: thanks for pointing to the right direction which I had overlooked at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#child-routing-component